# Deployment error: failed to launch: determine start command: process type web was not found

Tags: node.js, vite, svelte, sveltekit

Currently recieving an error when attempting to deploy a svelte vite app on Digital Ocean. Does anyone know what is needed to be altered to correct the error described below?

The code builds & runs successfully locally using `npm run dev`. Within the digital ocean site it is set up to deploy from a github repo. The code builds succcessfully & then in the "Deploy logs" this is the error:
 `ERROR: failed to launch: determine start command: process type web was not found`

in the package.json this is what the scripts sections looks like:

```
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite dev",
        "build": "vite build",
        "prod": "vite dev --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080",
        "test": "npm run test:integration && npm run test:unit",
        "check": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json",
        "check:watch": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json --watch",
        "lint": "prettier --check . && eslint .",
        "format": "prettier --write .",
        "test:integration": "playwright test",
        "test:unit": "vitest",
        "postbuild": "node --experimental-json-modules ./generate-sitemap.js"
    },
```